# Empty Space Between Logo and menu bar in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am using boot strap for my design.I have used nav bar for drop down purpose.when i try to iclude Logo,Signin/signup above this menu its not getting properly aligned.So when i used another nav bar it is getting alligned but lot of empty space between the two.
[link](http://rewardsinn.com/home2.php)

**Here is the code:**

<

```
nav class="navbar navbar-static">
  <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="#project-link"> <img class="img-responsive col-md-4" src="final1.jpg"> </a>
    <div > </div>
    <div class="pull-right"> <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-info">Sign In</a> </div>
    <div class="pull-right col-md-1"> <a href="#1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#1" class="btn btn-primary btn-info">Sign Up</a> </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="http://rewardsinn.com/categories.php" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-brand" data-toggle="dropdown"></a> </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://rewardsinn.com/home2.php">Home</a> </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-brand" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories<b class="caret"></b></a>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left"  method="post" action="search.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="search" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Store">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.nav-collapse --> 
</nav>
```

Comment: here is link http://rewardsinn.com/home2.php

Comment: its a very big code please specify the code that is to the point.

Comment: I have removed the unncessary part.Here are two nav bars with unncessary space.here is link rewardsinn.com/home2.php.kindly tell me how to remove that space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` element on the site has `margin-top: 50px` and also `padding-top: 50px` remove it and you shall be fine.

But it's hard to say which file to edit since your styles' structure is completely messed up. Editing `bootstrap.css` wont help since there are other files that control looks of the `body` element. Like this misterious `home2.php:605` in the Dev Tools which leads to some JS code.

And by the way, StackOverFlow is not the site where people are solving your code problems for free while you are paid for that. It is not about it at all. You are missing the point of the resource, just saying.

Comment: we gave it to designers first who did a horrible job.so i had to redo everything.since budget is a constraint i am learning myself to do it.check:rewardsinn.com/index.php for their work

Comment: we gave it to designers first who did a horrible job.so i had to redo everything.since budget is a constraint i am learning myself to do it.check:rewardsinn.com/index.php for their work.Thanks for helping me...I am new to this.We were cheated and the code was full of tables when he delivered.

Comment: @user3661273 You are welcome, but next time try to make your question look like pure programming without involving the commercial stuff. That's not what this site is for. And if my answer was a solution, then mark it with a green check.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you asking but if is for the space between the two navbar you can remove it by adding `margin-button:0` to the navbar statics like this

in your css

```
.navbar.navbar-static {
   margin-button:0
}
```

If you wanna remove the top space

```
body {
  padding-top:0;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The navbar in bootstrap has a default margin-bottom of 20px. You need to change that to 0.

Give your top navbar with the logo a class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static no-margin">
....
</nav>
```

In your stylesheet

```
.no-margin{
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's quite an awful workaround since the code already have an ID for the Main Navbar, why create one more selector and stacking classess?

Comment: @knitevision Thanks. I'll keep that in mind when I'm making webpages.